# Why does performing OCR in Adobe create a much larger document?

Tags: compression, adobe-acrobat, osx-yosemite, ocr

I'm using Adobe Acrobat Pro XI on Macintosh OS X Yosemite and I've noticed that doing OCR sometimes creates a much larger document.  For example, I scanned a four page document and got a 458K document, then I did OCR and it ended up being 1.8MB.   It makes no sense to me for it to more than triple the size of the document.  Perhaps it is due to the down sample option in the OCR to 300dpi.  The original document was scanned at 300dpi already, so no need to down sample.  Is there a way to do OCR and disable Acrobat doing the down sample?

Why is Adobe making the document so much bigger after doing OCR, and I can I perform OCR in Acrobat without this huge overhead being added to the size?

Note, I subsequently scanned the document again, and this time did OCR as part of the scan dialog instead of a later step and I got a document of 241K.  So I have a workaround, but why is it so different to do as two steps instead of just one?

Comment: Because adding the OCR information adds overhead.  The task creates a new document in the process also, so you would have to optimize the new document, just like you optimized the original one.

Comment: @Ramhound I agree that OCR adds information, but the textual and related information being added should be very small in comparison to an image, and not triple the file size.